# Golang promptui : is there a way to point to previously selected value

Tags: go, command-line-interface

I am implementing a CLI and there I have a select list to choose from an array of values.

```
cellTemplate := &promptui.SelectTemplates{
    Label:    "{{ . }}",
    Active:   "\U000027A4 {{ .| cyan }}",
    Inactive: "  {{ . | white }}",
    Selected: green("\U00002713 ") + boldWhite("cell context: ") + "{{ .  | faint }}",
    Help: faint("[Use arrow keys]"),
}

cellPrompt := promptui.Select{
    Label: yellow("?") + " Select a cell cluster",
    Items: <Array of items>,
    Templates: cellTemplate,
}
```

[image: Screen Shot]

This works fine but once I select an item, the next time I list the items, I want to point it to the item I previously selected. If I selected second item, it when I enter the command to list items, it should look like this.

[image: Screen Shot]

I can save get the key and value of the previously selected item. Any idea?

Is it possible?

Comment: afaik, promptui doesn't provide any event like on select, on change, etc. I think you might need to modify the source code to achieve what you need

Comment: @afaik ok, I guess this is a limitation. I just wanted to confirm it.